# Is there a way in SQL to join a table and instead of each joined item creating a new row, join it as a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have some data that I have a table and when I join another table that has multiple matches but each are unique, it creates a new row. Is there a way to get it to join into a specific column where the column name is the name in tblCatDetails and the value is whatever is in tblCatData in CatData? The tables look similar to this example...

1

`+--------+
| tblCat |
+--------+
| id     |
+--------+`

2

`+-------------+
| tblCatData  |
+-------------+
| id          |
| CatID       |
| CatDetailID |
| CatData     |
+-------------+`

3

`+---------------+
| tblCatDetails |
+---------------+
| id            |
| detailName    |
+---------------+`

some sample data could be

table 1

`+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+`

table 2

`+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| id | CatID | CatDetailID |    CatData     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
|  1 |     1 |           1 | black          |
|  2 |     1 |           2 | 4              |
|  3 |     1 |           3 | a lot          |
|  4 |     2 |           1 | orange         |
|  5 |     2 |           2 | 4              |
|  6 |     2 |           3 | not very often |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+`

table 3

`+----+----------------+
| id |   DetailName   |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | color          |
|  2 | number of legs |
|  3 | meow frequency |
+----+----------------+`

Is there a way to pop this bad boy out using joins and make it look like...

`+----+--------+----------------+----------------+
| id | color  | number of legs | meow frequency |
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+
|  1 | black  |              4 | a lot          |
|  2 | orange |              4 | not very often |
+----+--------+----------------+----------------+`

Comment: Dynamic pivoter needed pronto

Comment: Your google search string is `sql server pivot queries`.

Comment: Alright I will take a look.

Comment: Your best bet is to never use this sort of EAV design in a relational database.

Comment: I agree and questioned it when I first saw the design. I do not see how it is beneficial.